# How to detect contours width and height in android opencv

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing

i created contours and draw a rectangle. now  need to detect my rectangle width and height how do do it?

```
ArrayList<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
Imgproc.findContours(ImageMatout, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL,Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
Core.rectangle(ImageMatin, rect.tl(), rect.br(), new Scalar(255, 0, 0),2);  
//double h = ??
//double w = ??
```

Comment: ohh.. i found it `double h = rect.height;`

Answer (score 0):

try this method 1:`rect.width` for width and `rect.height` for height

OR Method 2:

```
double x1= rect.tl().x;
double y1= rect.tl().y;
double x2=  rect.br().x;
double y2= rect.br().y;
```

(x1,y1) is the coordinate point of the top-left corner of rectangle.
(x2,y2) is the coordinate point of the Bottom-Right corner of rectangle.
Height and width can be calculated as

```
double height=x2-x1;   //height or length
double width=y2-y1;    // width or breadth
```